# Dynamic Command Class in Annotated Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

As of Spring MVC 3, `AbstractCommandController` is deprecated so you can no longer specify the command class in `setCommandClass()`. Instead you hard-code the command class in the parameter list of a request handler. For example,

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void show(HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee)
```

My problem is that I'm developing a generic page that allows the user to edit a generic bean, so the command class isn't known until the run-time. If the variable `beanClass` holds the command class, with `AbstractCommandController`, you would simply do the following,

```
setCommandClass(beanClass)
```

Since I can't declare the command object as a method parameter, is there any way to have Spring bind request parameters to a generic bean in the body of the request handler?

Comment: What do you mean by a "generic bean"?

Comment: I meant a POJO. Normally, a controller uses a specific bean as its command object, but my controller needs to use any bean whose type isn't known until the runtime. The type comes from a service object.

Comment: But if the type isn't known at compile time, how are you going to use it in your code?

Comment: You can think of it as something similar to a JavaBeans property editor in some Swing-based tool. You specify a JavaBeans class you want to edit and the tool loads it to an editor. In my case, the list of beans to configure is known at compile time, but I'd like them to share the same controller since it would be redundant to have a different controller for each bean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instantiation of the command object is the only place where Spring needs to know a command class. However, you can override it with `@ModelAttribute`-annotated method:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public void show(HttpServletRequest request, 
    @ModelAttribute("objectToShow") Object objectToShow) 
{
    ...
}

@ModelAttribute("objectToShow")
public Object createCommandObject() {
    return getCommandClass().newInstance();
}
```

By the way, Spring also works fine with the real generics:

```
public abstract class GenericController<T> {
    @RequestMapping("/edit")  
    public ModelAndView edit(@ModelAttribute("t") T t) { ... }
}

@Controller @RequestMapping("/foo")
public class FooController extends GenericController<Foo> { ... }
```