# Using a generic class as argument for ModelAtribute

Tags: java, spring, generics

I have a generic controller where the methods on it have a signature similar to it:

```
public String cadastra(@ModelAttribute("object") E object, BindingResult result)
```

this `object` in the derived controller, need have the same name of an entity class which the controller is created for (ex.: a controller named UsuarioController act over an entity class Usuario).

My thought was create a generic class named `object` and all my entities be derived from this class. Is there any way to make this work? For each one of this controllers, I have the follow html forms which expect a method with this signature:

```
<%@ include file="../include/header.jsp" %>

<form:form class="form" role="form" action="${action}" method="post">

    <table>
        <c:forEach var="item" items="${elements}">
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="${item}">${item}</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input type="" path="${item}" /></td> 
        </tr>
        </c:forEach>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Cadastrar</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</form:form>

<%@ include file="../include/result.jsp" %>

<%@ include file="../include/footer.jsp" %>
```

Comment: Have you tried it? If so, what errors are you facing?

Comment: Dublicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897185/dynamic-command-class-in-annotated-controller